# Check which one of values in array is in the string PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
        $myArray= array(
        "Cold coffe", 
        "Cold water",
        "Disco", 
        "I love you"        
        );
```

And i have string:

```
$string = "My baby I love you"
```

I wanted to check if one of this values exsits in this string and i do it in this way:

```
        function match($needles, $haystack)
    {
        foreach($needles as $needle){
            if (strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    if(match($myArray, $string)){
       echo "Matching.";
    }
```

And this works ok, but i want to know which one of this values in $myArray exsits in this string and print that value, how i can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom `match` function, you can return the matching string (`$needle`), instead of returning `true`. [OP confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52629911/check-which-one-of-values-in-array-is-in-the-string-php/52629962?noredirect=1#comment92193734_52629962) that he just needs the value.

```
function match($needles, $haystack)
{
    foreach($needles as $needle){
        if (strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) {
            return $needle;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now, just print it out:

```
if( $needle = match($myArray, $string) ){
   echo "Matching Word: " . $needle;
}
```

Comment: You dont explain which array key is used, How do you get the string from `$myArray` afterwards?

Comment: @delboy1978uk because I return the value directly. I dont need to use key to get the value afterwards from array.

Comment: You don't but the OP probably does. If he can confirm i'll reverse it.

Comment: @delboy1978uk OP does not want the key. Question is very clear that he is looking for the value in the array which matches.

Comment: @delboy1978uk this is the question statement: "but i want to know which one of this values in $myArray exsits in this string and print that value"

Comment: "which one of this values in $myArray " sounds hell of a like he needs the array index

Comment: @delboy1978uk Let OP confirm. He just needs to print out the value. So it is quite obvious, that index is of no use.

Comment: That's what i said several comments ago

Comment: Hey guys. I'm very thankful for your answers. I just want the value, not the key.

Comment: un-downvoting then

Answer (score 1):

You just need to tweak your function slightly to use the array index:

```
<?php

 $myArray= array(
    "Cold coffe", 
    "Cold water",
    "Disco", 
    "I love you"        
    );

$string = "My baby I love you";

function match($needles, $haystack)
{
    foreach($needles as $index => $needle){
        if (strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) {
            return $index;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


if($index = match($myArray, $string)){
   echo "Matching array key ".$index . ", " . $myArray[$index];
}
```

> Output: Matching array key 3, I love you

See it here https://3v4l.org/JPNOF